# Recursive rendering of JSON tree with HTML elements (Input, Radio, etc.)

Tags: json, reactjs

I am quite new to React and working with JSON structures. I am trying to construct a recursive render of a JSON tree structure that dynamically renders individual HTML elements (e.g. radio buttons, dropdown menus, etc.) from the tree. I have seen other implementations, but they do not have nested HTML elements that differ from li, ul, etc. They also do not typically have different naming conventions further down the tree (e.g. attributes, options).

The tree looks like this:

```
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Animals",
        "color": "#e37939",
        "shape": "bounding_box",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "id": "1.1",
                "name": "Type",
                "type": "radio",
                "required": false,
                "options": [
                    {
                        "id": "1.1.1",
                        "optionName": "Cats",
                        "optionValue": "cats",
                        "options": [.... and so on

    };
```

What I ultimately what to achieve is to get to a format where one clicks the 'Animals button', which then renders the nested radio button, and if one selects the 'cats' option value it'd render the next dropdown menu. I have set up an initial set of methods, but I can't quite figure out how to dynamically render the next set of nested options when an option is clicked. I have created a React fiddle here: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-grothendieck-jknym

The biggest challenge is to get the nested recursive options embedded in an options group. I haven't been able to figure out how to do that yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a datastructure for what you want to achieve , altho i have tweaked it a bit as there are parts of it redundant but you can still keep both data structure and convert between them.it goes recursively as deep as you want it to go.

```
const prodList = [
 {
    id: "1",
    name: "Animals",
    options: [
      {
        id: "1.1",
        name: "Type",
        inputType: "radio",
        options: [
          {
            id: "1.1.1",
            name: "Cats",
            value: "Cats",
            inputType: "select",
            options: [
              { id: "1.1.1.1", name: "Siamese Grey", value: "Siamese Grey" },
              { id: "1.1.1.2", name: "Siamese Black", value: "Siamese Black" },
              { id: "1.1.1.3", name: "Siamese Cute", value: "Siamese Cute" },
              { id: "1.1.1.4", name: "House Cat", value: "House Cat" },
              { id: "1.1.1.5", name: "House Cat", value: "House Cat" }
            ]
          },
          { id: "1.1.2", name: "Dogs", value: "Dogs" },
          { id: "1.1.3", name: "Cows", value: "Cows" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

above is the data structure where you have "inputType" property that helps determining what component to show. we will have a basic component , a radio component and a select component of each type which can render each other inside them.

```
export default class ProductsPage extends Component {
  render() {
    let prodItems = prodList.map(p => {
      return <MainContentManager data={p} key={p.id} />;
    });
    return <div>{prodItems}</div>;
  }
}

class MainContentManager extends Component {
  render() {
    let renderObj = null;
    renderObj = basicMethod(renderObj, this.props.data);
    return (
      <div>
        <h6> {this.props.data.name}</h6>
        {renderObj}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class RadioButtonManager extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeOptionIndex: 0
    };
    this.handleInputClick = this.handleInputClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleInputClick(index) {
    this.setState({
      activeOptionIndex: index
    });
  }
  render() {
    let renderObj = null;
    let renderDat = null;
    renderDat = this.props.data.options.map((op, index) => {
      return (
        <label key={op.id}>
          <input
            type="radio"
            onChange={e => {
              this.handleInputClick(index);
            }}
            checked={index == this.state.activeOptionIndex ? true : false}
          />
          {op.name}
        </label>
      );
    });

    renderObj = basicMethod(renderObj, {
      options: [this.props.data.options[this.state.activeOptionIndex]]
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <h6> {this.props.data.name}</h6>
        {renderDat}
        {renderObj}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class SelectManager extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: "", activeOptionIndex: 0 };
    this.handleInputClick = this.handleInputClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputClick(value) {
    let activeOptionIndex = this.state.activeOptionIndex;
    if (this.props.data.options) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.props.data.options.length; i++) {
        if (this.props.data.options[i].value == value) {
          activeOptionIndex = i;
        }
      }
    }
    this.setState({
      value: value,
      activeOptionIndex: activeOptionIndex
    });
  }
  render() {
    let renderObj = null;
    let selectOptions = this.props.data.options.map((op, index) => {
      return (
        <option key={op.value} value={op.value}>
          {op.name}
        </option>
      );
    });
    renderObj = basicMethod(renderObj, {
      options: [this.props.data.options[this.state.activeOptionIndex]]
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <select
          onChange={e => {
            this.handleInputClick(e.target.value);
          }}
        >
          {selectOptions}
        </select>
        {renderObj}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function basicMethod(renderObj, data) {
  if (data && data.options) {
    renderObj = data.options.map(op => {
      !op && console.log(data);
      let comp = null;
      if (op.inputType == "radio") {
        comp = <RadioButtonManager data={op} key={op.id} />;
      } else if (op.inputType == "select") {
        comp = <SelectManager data={op} key={op.id} />;
      } else {
        comp = <MainContentManager data={op} key={op.id} />;
      }
      return comp;
    });
  }

  return renderObj;
}
```

ask anything if it is unclear or you want it a bit different.

Comment: That's a great implementation. It is smarter than the one that I subsequently came up with, which ultimately ended up being half iterative / half recursive. I suppose the danger with a recursive implementation is that you risk smashing your stack.

Comment: it wont be always recursive as when there are no more options it will just return null and recursion will stop